# Two different tables in one output in MySQL

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT t.dateline AS date,t.tid, t.subject, u.avatar,t.views, t.username, t.replies, u.profilepic, t.uid, p.thumbsup, t.firstpost, f.name, f.fid, p.message, a.updatetime, a.md5hash, a.uploadtime, a.aid, a.attachname, a.filename, a.thumbs, td.vidid, td.cat, td.portada
FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."threads t 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users u ON (u.uid=t.uid)
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."forums f ON (f.fid=t.fid)
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."xtattachments a ON (a.tid=t.tid)
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threadfields_data td ON (td.tid=t.tid)
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON (p.pid=t.firstpost)
WHERE t.fid IN ($f4id) AND t.uid IN ($show_post_list)  

UNION ALL

SELECT th.dateline AS date, th.thumbsup, th.uid
FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."thumbspostrating th 


ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$perpage).", ".$perpage);
```

Example:

1. Thread number one dateline: today
2. Like number one dateline: yesterday 1:10pm
3. Thread number two dateline: yesterday 1:09pm
4. Like number two dateline: yesterday 1:08pm
5. Like number three dateline: yesterday 1:07pm
6. Thread number three dateline: yesterday 1:05pm

I don’t know why this doesn’t work?
In `ORDER BY` <-- I need `t.dateline` and `l.dateline` in to one for do that example.

1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: define: `doesn't work`?

Comment: is uid  defined as a column here ??

Comment: 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Of course t.uid and th.uid

Comment: Are you having a laugh? You've completely changed the query and effectively the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it changes each time you answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do add as dateline to your select SELECT l.dateline as dateline , l.name, l.avatar.

That worked for me. If that does not work you can always do a select on your selects and then order that result it would read something like this

```
SELECT dateline, name, avatar FROM ( 
  SELECT t.dateline, t.name, u.avatar
  FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."threads t 
  LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users u ON (u.uid=t.uid)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT l.dateline, l.name, l.avatar
  FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."likes l 
  LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."treads t ON (t.uid=l.uid)
) as x
ORDER BY x.dateline DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: is uid a column here ??

Comment: It sends and error:
1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: Well you changed the complete query i see but if i see your new query indeed you change the number of columns and they are not equal. For union its necessary to have the same number of columns

Comment: Its for this example :/ the threads has more information : 
Thread number one dateline: today
Like number one dateline: yesterday 1:10pm
Thread number two dateline: yesterday 1:09pm
Like number two dateline: yesterday 1:08pm
Like number three dateline: yesterday 1:07pm
Thread number three dateline: yesterday 1:05pm

Comment: @JonathanNungaray If threads has more information and you really want to show it you still have to make sure that they have the same nr of colums. You could achieve this by simply adding something like this "" as username to assign empty values to virtual columns but if the data is that differnt i would not use a union because you have to do that for every column that threads has extra (and in the correct place)

Comment: Well is it another method for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` is only applied to the second query:

```
Select * From (
SELECT t.dateline, t.name, u.avatar
FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."threads t 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users u ON (u.uid=t.uid)

UNION ALL

SELECT l.dateline, l.name, l.avatar
FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."likes l 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."treads t ON (t.uid=l.uid) ) allData

ORDER BY allData.dateline DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```